# PIE, IE8, jQuery InnerFade and CSS3 border-radius - again

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I got a major issue with PIE and IE8.
first of all the CSS:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <style type="text/css">
    *.article_image img {
        position:relative;
        border-radius:20px;
        behavior:url(/js/PIE.htc);

    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML:

```
<div class="innerfade">
  <div class="article_image">
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The  is part of an "inner fade" Block with JQUERY innerfade tool. Today I guess thats whats causing the trouble.
This works fine in IE10 with the developer tools set to "IE8", display mode "IE8 standard". But does not work in "real" IE8. Any Idea why?

Comment: Ok. I guess it is some incompability between innerFade and PIE.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, enter your answer below for the benefit of others or delete the question.

Comment: I didn't find a solution. It is just some more information...

Comment: Then it should probably appear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a better solution or IE8 isn't used anymore, I'm using this ugly little workaround:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <div style="position:absolute;"><img style="width:20px;height:20px;" alt="corner" src="template/left_top.png"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;"><img style="width:20px;height:20px;" alt="corner" src="template/left_bottom.png"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;right:0px;"><img style="width:20px;height:20px;" alt="corner" src="template/right_top.png"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;"><img style="width:20px;height:20px;" alt="corner" src="template/right_bottom.png"></div>
<![endif]-->
```

works fine. But causes lots of work, if you want to change the background color...